# SQL command to create table

Tags: sql

I'm trying to run this queries but it does not working.Can anyone figure out whats the problem?

```
CREATE TABLE Hasagenre
(
    movieId INTEGER ,
    genreId INTEGER ,

    FOREIGN KEY (movieId) REFERENCES Movies ,
    FOREIGN KEY (genreId) REFERENCES Genres ,
    PRIMARY KEY movieId 
) ;
```

Comment: "it's not working" is not a good problem description. Please specify any errors you get or results you get compared to what you expected

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: `PRIMARY KEY movieId` should be: `PRIMARY KEY (movieId)`

Comment: Error starting at line 1 in command:
CREATE TABLE Hasagenre
(
   movieId INT ,
   genreId INT ,
   awais INT ,
   
   FOREIGN KEY movieId REFERENCES Movies,
   FOREIGN KEY genreId REFERENCES Genres,
   PRIMARY KEY movieId
) 
Error at Command Line:7 Column:15
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis
00906. 00000 -  "missing left parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: This above is the error i'm getting using oracle product

Answer (score 1):

The syntax to create the foreign key constraints is wrong. It should also specify the column name on the foreign key table.

```
CREATE TABLE Hasagenre
(
    movieId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    genreId INTEGER ,
    FOREIGN KEY (movieId) REFERENCES Movies(Column_name)
    FOREIGN KEY (genreId) REFERENCES Genres(column_name)
);
```

Comment: No, that's not required (at least not for all DBMS, see e.g. here: http://rextester.com/JJS82771)

Answer (score 1):

While referencing to another table in SQL, it is important to give the column name of both, the primary table and the referenced table, with which you will bind both the tables. So along with the name of the table movies, genre, etc., provide the common column name too. Suppose tables movies and genre have a column movieNo and genreNo respectively, we can write the query.

The correct query would be:

```
create table hasagenre
(    movieId INTEGER, 
    genreId INTEGER,
    Foreign Key (movieId) references Movies (movieNo),
    Foreign Key (genreId) references Genre (genreNo),
    Primary Key (movieId)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing the columns in the foreign key constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE Hasagenre
(
    movieId INTEGER ,
    genreId INTEGER ,

    FOREIGN KEY (movieId) REFERENCES Movies(xxx) ,
    FOREIGN KEY (genreId) REFERENCES Genres(xxx) ,
    PRIMARY KEY movieId 
) ;
```

See more at: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Answer (score 0):

People so far said that you have to specify column name you're referencing. Well, that's not entirely true; I guess that it depends on a database you use (which you didn't specify).

Here's an example, based on Oracle, which shows that you certainly don't have to do that. Of course, a column you're referencing has to be a primary or unique key.

```
SQL> create table movies
  2    (movieno number primary key,        --> primary key, which can then be referenced ...
  3     name    varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> create table hasagenre
  2    (movieid number,
  3     foreign key (movieid) references movies   --> ... while creating a foreign key
  4    );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to enclose the columns to the primary key constraint in parenthesis.

```
CREATE TABLE HASAGENRE
             (MOVIEID INTEGER,
              ...
              PRIMARY KEY (MOVIEID));
```